# Validation of Mat Card in Angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material2

Perhaps I've been spoiled for documentation, having previously worked with C#, or I haven't found the right way to go about the Angular docs, but I can't seem to find adequate documentation especially for Angular 5 related material design elements.

My specific question here is about validating a mat-card element of an Angular form **without** checking if:

1) the entire form is valid and

2) each individual field of the mat-card is valid.

Is there something analogous to the Page.isValid property of an ASP.NET app's page for this scenario?

Comment: There's no connection with a material card there. You have to validate your form, that is in a material card, but you don't validate a card. Please explain what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: You're right! At the moment I can't think of a use case where I wouldn't mind having a mat-card's fields invalid before proceeding to the next one. I'll make the edit.

Comment: So you have several material cards and you want to validate the form in each of them ?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes

Comment: @trichetriche I'll leave this as it is in case a future use case does come up unless someone objects. Anyhow, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I misread your second comment. Currently I have a single form with multiple mat-cards in it. However, I wouldn't mind changing the structure to have one form for each mat-card.

Comment: I'm confused with the requirements in your question, could you clarify? Are you trying to validate only a single control in your form? As previously mentioned, a ```mat-card``` element is not a form element, so there would be no validation done on the card itself, but validation could be done on the controls within the card.

Comment: @p4r1 In that case, is there a way to validate all the controls of the card, together?

Comment: @RahulSaha If you haven't yet, read through the [Angular docs on forms and validation](https://angular.io/guide/user-input), as they do a good job explaining the possible flows and validation for controls. Do the demos too. Each control within a form is either valid or invalid based on the rules you set up for the control, and the parent form is only valid when all it's subcontrols are valid.

Comment: @RahulSaha you ever validate all the controls of a form. If the controls are _also_ in another component, as i.e. a card, tha doesn't matter.